# boost program_options values with different types

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

How can I provide an option to the boost program_options, which will accept 3 values with different types: [int, int, float]?

For example:

```
./app_name --check-integrity 1 2.2 --do_something 2 2 2.5
```

I've tried to achieve that with a vector of boost::any.

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
po::option_descriptions desc("");

desc.add_options()
 ("opt", po::value<std::vector<boost::any> >()->multitoken(), "description");
```

But without success. This code causes:

```
/usr/include/boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical.hpp:243:13: error: static assertion failed: Target type is neither std::istream`able nor std::wistream`able
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG((result_t::value || boost::has_right_shift<std::basic_istream<wchar_t>, T >::value),
```

Any other idea?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `"which will accept 3 values with different types: [int, int, float]"`.  Can you provide some examples of what would be typed/accepted at the command line?

Answer (score 1):

> This is my recommended, simpler approach. I have added a true [multi-token option value parsing approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65152635/85371) as a separate answer for completeness.

You can use any streamable type. So, if you have types:

```
struct check {
    int i;
    double d;
};

struct something {
    int a;
    int b;
    double c;
};
```

You can define the options like:

```
opt.add_options()
    ("do_something,s", bpo::value<something>()->default_value(something{1,2,3}, "1 2 3"), "")
    ("check-integrity,c", bpo::value<check>()->default_value(check{1,0.1}, "1 0.1"), "")
    ("help", "");
```

> Note how you need to supply the stringified default value only if the type cannot be output-streamed (or the streamed format doesn't match the expected input format)

```
bpo::variables_map vm;

try {
    bpo::store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, opt), vm);

    bpo::notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("help")) {
        std::cout << opt << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << vm["do_something"].as<something>() << "\n";
    std::cout << vm["check-integrity"].as<check>() << "\n";
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

### Output Streaming: Simple Stuff

That's the usual stuff:

```
static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, check const& v) {
    return os << "check {" << v.i << ", " << v.d << "}";
}
static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, something const& v) {
    return os << "something {" << v.a << ", " << v.b << ", " << v.c << "}";
}
```

### Input Streaming: Get As Fancy As You Want

Here there are some slight caveats. First of them is that the `istream&` supplied from `program_options` is - by default - modified with the `std::noskipws` manipulator. You have to undo that in order to be able to read space separated data.

Next up, for any non-trivial parsing/validation task I'd suggest using something more sophisticated. But for the demo, this would suffice:

```
static inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, check& into) {
    return is >> std::skipws >> into.i >> into.d;
}
static inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, something& into) {
    return is >> std::skipws >> into.a >> into.b >> into.c;
}
```

### Demo Time

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ef83fb01d48e087)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bpo = boost::program_options;
struct check {
    int i;
    double d;
};

struct something {
    int a;
    int b;
    double c;
};

static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, check const& v) {
    return os << "check {" << v.i << ", " << v.d << "}";
}
static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, something const& v) {
    return os << "something {" << v.a << ", " << v.b << ", " << v.c << "}";
}
static inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, check& into) {
    return is >> std::skipws >> into.i >> into.d;
}
static inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, something& into) {
    return is >> std::skipws >> into.a >> into.b >> into.c;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    bpo::options_description opt("all options");

    opt.add_options()
        ("do_something,s", bpo::value<something>()->default_value(something{1,2,3}, "1 2 3"), "")
        ("check-integrity,c", bpo::value<check>()->default_value(check{1,0.1}, "1 0.1"), "")
        ("help", "");

    bpo::variables_map vm;

    try {
        bpo::store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, opt), vm);

        bpo::notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            std::cout << opt << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }

        std::cout << vm["do_something"].as<something>() << "\n";
        std::cout << vm["check-integrity"].as<check>() << "\n";
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
+ ./sotest --help
all options:
  -s [ --do_something ] arg (=1 2 3)
  -c [ --check-integrity ] arg (=1 0.1)
  --help 

+ ./sotest
something {1, 2, 3}
check {1, 0.1}
+ ./sotest --check ''
the argument for option '--check-integrity' is invalid
+ ./sotest --check oops
the argument ('oops') for option '--check-integrity' is invalid
+ ./sotest --check '8 8'
something {1, 2, 3}
check {8, 8}
+ ./sotest --do_something '11 22 .33'
something {11, 22, 0.33}
check {1, 0.1}
+ ./sotest --do_something '11 22 .33' --check '80 -8'
something {11, 22, 0.33}
check {80, -8}
```

Comment: This is my recommended, simpler approach. I have added a true [multi-token option value parsing approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65152635/85371) as a separate answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

I posted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65152300/85371) earlier, but I can just predict the follow-up question:

> But what if I want to allow `--check 1 3.14` instead of `--check "1 3.14"` or `--check '1 3.14'`?

That's not a bad question, and it's actually fair because that's the close reading of the original post.

I consider this not the best strategy because:

- it requires parsing into some intermediate vector of tokens
- requires manual conversion from these to the target type
- it makes for brittle command lines

  - it postpones validation of the option value until after command line parsing, the multitoken could have an unexpected *number* of value tokens and you wouldn't know until converting to the target type
  - it doesn't work at all when e.g. one of the token is negative. Because `--check 8 -8` will try to parse `-8` as an option

In general, it's a whole lot more work for less functionality.

### HOW would you do it anyways?

Let's assume the same target types as earlier:

```
struct check {
    int i;
    double d;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, check const& v) {
        return os << "check {" << v.i << ", " << v.d << "}";
    }
};

struct something {
    int a;
    int b;
    double c;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, something const& v) {
        return os << "something {" << v.a << ", " << v.b << ", " << v.c << "}";
    }
};
```

### Parsing Multi-Token

Now, you suggested `boost::any`, but we can be more specific. We know we only expect integers or doubles:

```
using ArgVal = boost::variant<int, double>;
using ArgVec = std::vector<ArgVal>;
```

> By being more specific, you catch more errors earlier (see e.g. the
> parse error when supplying `'oops'` as the value)

Now define the options as multi-token:

```
opt.add_options()
    ("do_something,s", bpo::value<ArgVec>()
        ->multitoken()
        ->default_value({1,2,3}, "1 2 3"), "")
    ("check-integrity,c", bpo::value<ArgVec>()
         ->multitoken()
         ->default_value({1,0.1}, "1 0.1"), "")
    ("help", "");
```

So far, I think that's actually pretty elegant.

Writing the rest of the demo program the way we'd like it to read:

```
bpo::variables_map vm;

try {
    bpo::store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, opt), vm);

    bpo::notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("help")) {
        std::cout << opt << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << as_check(vm["check-integrity"].as<ArgVec>()) << "\n";
    std::cout << as_something(vm["do_something"].as<ArgVec>()) << "\n";
} catch (std::exception const& e) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR " << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

This leaves a few loose ends:

- parsing
- conversion (what are `as_check` and `as_something`?)

### Parsing `ArgVal`

Like before we can simply provide an input streaming operator for the type. And as we said [back then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65152300/85371) you can "Get As Fancy As You Want".

Let's employ Spirit X3 to get a lot of mileage for little effort:

```
static inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ArgVal& into) {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    std::string arg;
    getline(is, arg);

    x3::real_parser<double, x3::strict_real_policies<double> > real_;
    if (!phrase_parse(
            begin(arg), end(arg),
            (real_ | x3::int_) >> x3::eoi,
            x3::blank,
            into))
    {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return is;
}
```

This time we embrace the `noskipws` because it convenes us, getting the full argument into a string.

Then, we parse it into a strict double OR an int.

> By using strict real policies, we avoid parsing any integer number as a double, because later down the road we don't want to allow conversion from double to int (potentially losing information).

### Converting

We need accessors to extract integer or double values. We will allow conversion from int to double since that never loses precision (`--check 8 8` is as valid as `--check 8 8.0`).

```
static int as_int(ArgVal const& a) {
    return boost::get<int>(a);
}

static double as_double(ArgVal const& a) {
    if (auto pi = boost::get<int>(&a))
        return *pi; // non-lossy conversion allowed
    return boost::get<double>(a);
}
```

Now we can express the higher level conversions to target types in terms of the `as_int` and `as_double` helpers:

```
static check as_check(ArgVec const& av) {
    try { 
        if (av.size() != 2) throw "up"; 
        return { as_int(av.at(0)), as_double(av.at(1)) };
    } catch(...) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("expected check (int, double)");
    }
}

static something as_something(ArgVec const& av) {
    try { 
        if (av.size() != 3) throw "up"; 
        return { as_int(av.at(0)), as_int(av.at(1)), as_double(av.at(2)) };
    } catch(...) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("expected something (int, int, double)");
    }
}
```

> I tried to write defensively, but not in particular good style. The code is safe, though.

### DEMO TIME

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/126506efe757fdd6)**

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace bpo = boost::program_options;

    struct check {
        int i;
        double d;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, check const& v) {
            return os << "check {" << v.i << ", " << v.d << "}";
        }
    };

    struct something {
        int a;
        int b;
        double c;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, something const& v) {
            return os << "something {" << v.a << ", " << v.b << ", " << v.c << "}";
        }
    };

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
using ArgVal = boost::variant<int, double>;
using ArgVec = std::vector<ArgVal>;

static inline std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ArgVal& into) {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    std::string arg;
    getline(is, arg);

    x3::real_parser<double, x3::strict_real_policies<double> > real_;
    if (!phrase_parse(
            begin(arg), end(arg),
            (real_ | x3::int_) >> x3::eoi,
            x3::blank,
            into))
    {
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }
    return is;
}

static int as_int(ArgVal const& a) {
    return boost::get<int>(a);
}

static double as_double(ArgVal const& a) {
    if (auto pi = boost::get<int>(&a))
        return *pi; // non-lossy conversion allowed
    return boost::get<double>(a);
}

static check as_check(ArgVec const& av) {
    try { 
        if (av.size() != 2) throw "up"; 
        return { as_int(av.at(0)), as_double(av.at(1)) };
    } catch(...) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("expected check (int, double)");
    }
}

static something as_something(ArgVec const& av) {
    try { 
        if (av.size() != 3) throw "up"; 
        return { as_int(av.at(0)), as_int(av.at(1)), as_double(av.at(2)) };
    } catch(...) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("expected something (int, int, double)");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    bpo::options_description opt("all options");

    opt.add_options()
        ("do_something,s", bpo::value<ArgVec>()
            ->multitoken()
            ->default_value({1,2,3}, "1 2 3"), "")
        ("check-integrity,c", bpo::value<ArgVec>()
             ->multitoken()
             ->default_value({1,0.1}, "1 0.1"), "")
        ("help", "");

    bpo::variables_map vm;

    try {
        bpo::store(parse_command_line(argc, argv, opt), vm);

        bpo::notify(vm);

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            std::cout << opt << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }

        std::cout << as_check(vm["check-integrity"].as<ArgVec>()) << "\n";
        std::cout << as_something(vm["do_something"].as<ArgVec>()) << "\n";
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
+ ./sotest --help
all options:
  -s [ --do_something ] arg (=1 2 3)
  -c [ --check-integrity ] arg (=1 0.1)
  --help 

+ ./sotest
check {1, 0.1}
something {1, 2, 3}
+ ./sotest --check ''
ERROR the argument for option '--check-integrity' is invalid
+ ./sotest --check oops
ERROR the argument ('oops') for option '--check-integrity' is invalid
+ ./sotest --check 8 8
check {8, 8}
something {1, 2, 3}
+ ./sotest --do_something 11 22 .33
check {1, 0.1}
something {11, 22, 0.33}
+ ./sotest --do_something 11 22 .33 --check 80 8
check {80, 8}
something {11, 22, 0.33}
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that you need to define type priority.

Which should be considered to deserialise first.

Consider making it of a [string type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/string) and cast back using [boost::lexical_cast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).